# How to create layout like on the picture?

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

That will be listview row.
Orange background is btn_default_small_selected:

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_default_small_selected"
```

Comment: So, what's the question? What you actually don't understand?

Comment: How to create second TextView element with fixed width and located at the right, when first TextView should be located at the left and should take the whole remaining space.

Comment: what part are you having a problem with?

Comment: I tried different approaches and looks like none of them works. So, I need to see exact values of 'layout_width', 'layout_gravity', 'layout_weight' for both TextViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you close. Basically, you'll define the orange box first. You just need a NinePatch for the orange gradient to set as the TextView background. Give it some margins (to keep the orange away from the edges), and some padding (to keep the text away from the edge of the orange box). Then add the TextView for "Palace", and align it to the left, and set the right edge "toLeftOf" the first TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_background_ninepatch"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timetext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_background_ninepatch"
        android:text="1:25 - 4:50"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nametext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/timetext"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Palace"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_background_ninepatch"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timetext"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/orange_background_ninepatch"
        android:text="1:25 - 4:50"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nametext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/timetext"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageview"
        android:text="Palace"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

NinePatch:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @kcoppock. If I need to add ImageView on the left side, should I add it at the end with `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/nametext"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`?

Comment: Close! But you'll actually want to add it in between the two TextViews, give it `alignParentLeft` but not `toLeftOf`. Then give the `nametext` TextView a `toRightOf` attribute referring to the ImageView.

Comment: @kcoppock, the image should be at the left: image, nametext, timetext.

Comment: I know. Trust me, it works as I stated. I've added an example above I threw together with a couple of 9-patch images, and the XML to go with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However my result looks differently from your image ;). Could you please advise how to make left and right margins on the timetext field? So, it will look like "    1:25 - 4:50     " instead of "1:25 - 4:50".

Comment: Oh, I just defined padding in the 9-patch image itself, which I've edited into the post for your reference. The bottom and right bars define the content area.